# Excel Download data and display in worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, download

I'm looking for a way to download data from a server and then display it in a worksheet.
So far I've created two worksheets `Home` & `Sites`

On the Home worksheet I have two cells D19 & D20 which are used for the users username and password.  What I'm trying to do is add a download button so when they click it there username and password are submitted to the server and the details are then downloaded.

The servers URL is in this format:
http://example.com?usr=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD

The downloaded results are a string of data with multiple comma separated values. Each new entry is on a new line: eg:

```
"NW21-A76","Upstate","798952124"
"NP54-P87","Local","798927272"
"SK06-001","N/A","543666788"
```

I need to take this data and split it on the commas, writing the values to the Sites worksheet.
The first value in B10, the second C10 and the third in D10. The new row of data in B11,C11,D11 etc.

Can anyone give me some ideas or pointers on how I can do this ?

Thanks

Update.
I've got this working, but the writing to the rows and cells is very slow.
Any better way to do this ?

```
Private Sub To_Excel()
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Dim sResponse  As String
    Dim sURL As String
    destRow = 10
    
    user = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("A1")
    pwd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("A2")
    
    
    sURL = "http://example.com?user=" & user & "&upassword=" & pwd

    'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
    oXMLHTTP.send
    sResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText

    sResponse = Replace(sResponse, vbCrLf, vbCr)
    sResponse = Replace(sResponse, vbLf, vbCr)
    sResponse = Replace(sResponse, """", "")
    rowData = Split(sResponse, vbCr)
 
    If (InStr(sResponse, "ERROR")) Then
        MsgBox "Error: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sResponse
        End
    End If
 
For Counter = 0 To UBound(rowData)
    Row = rowData(Counter)
    
    Column = Split(Row, ",")
    valA = Column(0)
    valB = Column(1)
    valC = Column(2)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sites").Cells(destRow, 2) = valA
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sites").Cells(destRow, 3) = valB
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sites").Cells(destRow, 4) = valB
    destRow = destRow + 1
    
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: So far I've managed to get the data downloading in to a string calls `sResponse` and write it all into one cell on the Sites worksheet.  I need to work out how to loop though the string breaking on new lines and then writing out the individual cells.

Comment: Split the cell value by a vbNewLine delimiter or use the TextToColumns method based on the same idea. Think you'll find enough examples by yourself. @Rocket

Comment: I've updated my original post, I have this working but the writing is very slow.
Any better way to do this ? Thanks

Comment: @Rocket You can dump an Array straight into the Cells: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sites"): .Range(.Cells(destRow,2), .Cells(destRow, 4)).Value = Split(Row, ","): End With`  Changing `Application.Calculation` and `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `xlCalculationManual` and `False` while it processes might also make things faster?

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know how I get on.

Comment: @Chronocidal this seems much faster Thanks. One issue I have it applies the Row data to cells 2, 3 & 4. The first value to 2, second to 3 and last to 4. I need First value to 4, second value to 3 and last value to 2. So swapping the first and last values. Any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the text file to temporary file and open as a workbook. Extract the data to an array, copy to another array reversing the columns and write to sheet. Close and delete temporary file.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub To_Excel()

    Const URL = "http://example.com"
    Const STARTROW = 10
    
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, sResponse  As String, sUrl As String
    Dim user As String, pwd As String
     
    'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
        user = .Range("A1")
        pwd = .Range("A2")
    End With

    sUrl = URL & "?user=" & user & "&upassword=" & pwd
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sUrl, False
    oXMLHTTP.send
    sResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText
 
    'Debug.Print sResponse
    If (InStr(sResponse, "ERROR")) Then
        MsgBox "Error: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sResponse
        End
    End If
    
    ' save to temp file
    Dim FSO As Object, ts As Object, tmpFile As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    tmpFile = Environ("Temp") & "\~tmp.csv"
    'Debug.Print tmpFile
    
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(tmpFile)
    ts.write sResponse
    ts.Close
    'Shell "notepad.exe " & tmpFile
    
    Dim wbCsv As Workbook
    Dim arIn, arOut
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol
     
    ' open temp file as workbook
    Set wbCsv = Workbooks.Open(tmpFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wbCsv.Sheets(1)
        arIn = .UsedRange.Value
        lastRow = UBound(arIn)
        lastCol = UBound(arIn, 2)
         
        ' reverse columns
        ReDim arOut(1 To lastRow, 1 To lastCol)
        For r = 1 To lastRow
            For c = 1 To lastCol
               arOut(r, c) = arIn(r, lastCol - c + 1)
            Next
        Next
        wbCsv.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    ' remove temp file
    Kill tmpFile
    
    ' write data to sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sites")
      .Range("B" & STARTROW).Resize(lastRow, lastCol).Value = arOut
      .Columns("B:D").AutoFit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox lastRow & " rows downloded", vbInformation

End Sub
```